# JQuery to change the color of last 3 characters on the cell in a Sharepoint List

Tags: jquery, sharepoint

On a Sharepoint List, I want to use JQuery to first check if the List cell  contains the text ABC, and if so, I want to change the color of only the ABC which is always the last 3 characters on the cell . In the following code, I was able to achieve everything but it is coloring the entire cell instead of just the ABC. How do I modify my code to just color the ABC or the last 3 characters?

```
$(window).load(function(){
    $(document).ready(function() {
       $('.td-id:contains("ABC")').css('color', 'green'); 
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Regex you can find last 3 character of string if it's contain 'ABC'. Replace your last 3 character  and wrap with some element with class. Apply desire CSS .

Example:

```js
$(".td-id:contains('ABC')").html(function(_, html) {
  return html.replace(/(.{1,3})$/, '<span class="someclass">$1</span>');
});
```

```css
.someclass {
  background-color: yellow
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class='td-id'>ABC123</span>
```

Comment: Brilliant! It worked. I am new to Regex. Do you mind explaining the syntax /(.{1,3})$/